# In DB2 SQL RegEx, how can a conditional replacement be done without CASE WHEN END..?

Tags: db2, regex-group, db2-400

I have a DB2 v7r3 SQL SELECT statement with three instances of REGEXP_SUBSTR(), all with the same regex pattern string, each of which extract one of three groups.

I'd like to change the first SUBSTR to REGEXP_REPLACE() to do a conditional replacement if there's no match, to insert a default value similarly to the ELSE section of a CASE...END. But I can't make it work. I could easily use a CASE, but it seems more compact & efficient to use RegEx.

For example, I have descriptions of food containers sizes, in various states of completeness:

- 12X125
- 6X350
- 1X1500
- 1500ML
- 1000

The last two don't have the 'nnX' part at the beginning, in which case '1X' is assumed and needs to be inserted.

This is my current working pattern string:

`^(?:(\d{1,3})(?:X))?((?:\d{1,4})(?:\.\d{1,3})?)(L|ML|PK|Z|)$`

The groups returned are: quantity, size, and unit.

But only the first group needs the conditional replacement:

`(?:(\d{1,3})(?:X))?`

This RexEgg [webpage](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-trick-conditional-replacement.html) describes the `(?=...)` operator, and it seems to be what I need, but I'm not sure. It's in the list of [operators](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm#rbafzregexp_like__regexp_likecontrol) for my version of DB2, but I can't make it work. Frankly, it's a bit deeper than my regex knowledge, and I can't even make it work in my favorite online regex tester, [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

So...does anyone have any idea or suggestions..? Thanks.

Comment: While REGEX may be more compact and elegant, if it is easy enough to just use a CASE expression and built in functions, those will generally perform much better.

Comment: Yes...elegant is the word I didn't know I needed. And of course there is such a thing as spending too much time on a problem. I thought I would explore it because such situations usually teach me something. Also...I wasn't sure what the efficiency would be in comparison between the regex engine and the optimizer. I was planning to test it on a few million rows once I got it working. I wasn't sure if/how much of the regex activity was handled deterministically like other chunks of SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (replace "digits not followed by X_or_digit"):

```
with t(s) as (values
  '12X125'
, '6X350'
, '1X1500'
, '1500'
, '1125'
)
select regexp_replace(s, '^([\d]+(?![X\d]))', '1X\1')
from t;
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you. You taught me two things: 1) The answer I needed, it works perfectly, and 2) Wow, I had no idea that syntax could be used for a CTE (with()), and it will come in very handy. I'm looking at the IBM online documentation for it now, and that syntax isn't very obvious. But under the VALUES statement (which directs forward to Queries > Fullselect), it does have a paragraph about it, and a number of other very interesting bits. Thanks..!

Comment: @spinjector Just in case. The following convenient syntax (without CTE) is supported as well (at least in 7.3): `select * from table(values (v11, ..., v1N), ..., (vM1, ..., vMN)) t (col1, ..., colN)`